# Put a file in a Firebase Storage Bucket

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I can see in the [Firebase Storage docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) how to put files into the root bucket with

`firebase.storage().ref('foldername/filename.jpg').put(file)`

How do I put files into an existing Firebase Storage bucket (not the root bucket)?  I'm creating a web app with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It eventually occurred to me to look at the configuration that initialized the app.  That is where we set the bucket name.  It can be changed to any bucket as needed (not just the root bucket).  This prompts the question - what value do buckets actually provide if we are constrained to a single bucket per app? - [Multiple Firebase Storage Buckets in One App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48727113/3465372).