# Multiple Firebase Storage Buckets in One App

Tags: firebase-storage

Is it possible for one app to use multiple Firebase Storage buckets?  Since we need to configure an app upon initialization to use a single bucket, I'm a bit confused about the value of having multi-bucket functionality.

Comment: I guess if you have multiple apps pointed to a single Firebase, it could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same situation. This worked for me. Hope it can help someone else too :)

```
// Add your bucket name here which is not in your GoogleService-info.plist file for your current app.

let storage = Storage.storage(url: "gs://your.storageBucketname.here")

let gsReference = storage.reference(forURL: firestoreLink)
```

Answer (score 1):

from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#use_multiple_storage_buckets

```js
// Get a non-default Storage bucket
var storage = firebase.app().storage("gs://my-custom-bucket");
```